# load website in to a page via ajax or iframe and avoid navigation

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, jquery

This is what i need to do.

there is a web page and another website, both are hosted in same domain. i want to load that whole web site in to a div or iframe of that web page. similar example for this is a free proxy browser like hidemyass.com.

i know this can be easily done but the point is that i also need to avoid navigation. say that the web site has 2 pages called a.htm and b.htm . there is a link to b.htm from a.htm. so when some one click the link on a.htm, the browser will redirect to b.htm

when i embed that a.htm in a part of my page, if some one click the link; it will redirect to the b.htm in browser. what i want to do is that avoid that redirect and when some one click on the link, b.htm should load in my page itself.

i have no way to change that website(in this case a.htm and b.htm), everything should be done in that page.

how can i achieve this?

Comment: `<iframe seamless="seamless">` should do just that but apparently no browser supports this feature correctly yet.

Comment: ya i read about this. this is in HTML5 isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's HTML5. MDN says that currently only Chrome supports it but in other places you can read that Chrome support is also incomplete/broken.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking at link clicks and not navigation via JavaScript then the following code should do:

```js
<iframe id="frame" src="a.html"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function onClick(event)
  {
    var link = event.target;
    while (link && link.localName != "a")
      link = link.parentNode;

    if (link && !link.hasAttribute("target"))
      link.setAttribute("target", "_parent");
  }

  // Listen to clicks inside the frame
  document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.addEventListener("click", onClick, false);
</script>
```

This will check the links the user clicks on and add `target="_parent"` attribute to them if no explicit target is defined. This means that links targeted at a new window/tab will still work as usual, links meant to replace the current page will replace the parent document instead. But this only works of course as long as the JavaScript code in `a.html` doesn't interfere.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to skip the link from your page only, you can add onclick handle to you link and return false when the frame has not completely loaded

this is the script

```
function checkLink(){
  if (canNavigate){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

but if you want to disable navigation on browser address you have to do like linkbuck website

http://c6f11ddd.linkbucks.com/url/http://www.google.com

linkbuck will not allow you to navigate away while ads has not been loaded yet.
They archive this by using these code, you should investigate it

```
Buster: function () {
  var interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (Lbjs.IsClick) {
     clearInterval(interval);
    }
    else if (Lbjs.Unload > 0) {
     Lbjs.Unload -= 2;
     window.top.location.replace("/cancelnavigation/");
     Lbjs.NavigationNotice();
    }
  }, 1);
  var clearDelay = (this.Countdown > 0) ? this.Countdown : 8;
  setTimeout(function () { clearInterval(interval); }, clearDelay * 1000);
},
NavigationNotice: function () {
  var navNotice = document.getElementById("navNotice");
  navNotice.innerHTML = "<span class=\"warning\" style=\"text-align:center;height:20px;width: 400px;padding: 10px;\"><b>Request Cancelled</b> - Navigation is disabled for 8 Seconds...</span>";
  if (navNotice.style.display == "none") {
    this.Fader.FadeIn(navNotice, 200, function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
      Lbjs.Fader.FadeOut(navNotice, 200, null);
    }, 1500);
  });
}
```